# How to interrupt a single, long-lasting command within a Runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, ocr

I have a single, fairly long-lasting command in my Java; say, 20 seconds running time on average. It's a call to the Tesseract OCR library that runs its OCR algorithm on an image.

```
String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
```

I have this encapsulated within a Runnable so that it doesn't cause the UI thread to hang, but I also want the user to be able to cancel the OCR with the push of a button.

Ideally, I would want it to run

```
baseApi.end()
```

once the button is pressed, but I don't see how to do so using myThread.interrupt, as there's no way I can see to check for Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted(). I could encapsulate the baseApi.getUTF8Text() call within a

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
...
}
```

block, but as the thread simply spends 20 seconds on baseApi.getUTF8Text(), it wouldn't even notice that the interrupted flag had been set to true until it completed the OCR algorithm regardless.

Is there any way to interrupt/stop this thread without needing to check the interrupted flag, or some way to do so that won't get hung waiting for baseApi.getUTF8Text() to complete? Please let me know if I'm not being clear here.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)?  It sounds like exactly what you need, plus there's a cancel method, and an isCancelled() method.

Comment: Sounds like I may need to use an Asynctask instead of a Runnable. I'll look into it and report back.

Comment: Ok, so. I did as suggested, and rolled it all into an Asynctask. In onPreExecute, I set a button's onClick to include a call to myOCRTask.cancel(true). However, if I click it, after ~20 seconds I still get confirmation that the long-running task completed, so it's still going in the background. Any idea why? Should I list my new code?

Comment: When you override onCancelled() is it being called?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize I needed to explicitly override onCanceled(), that's almost certainly why. Let me get back on this.

Comment: Ok, it looks like onCancelled() is being called, but only once the task completes, e.g. after around ~20 seconds. It isn't actually killing the long-running task mid-run, just waiting for it to end. onPostExecute() is not being called, just onCancelled(). Why is it not forcing the task to end as desired? Bleh.

Comment: From the docs: "Runs on the UI thread after cancel(boolean) is invoked and doInBackground(Object[]) has finished.

The default implementation simply invokes onCancelled() and ignores the result. If you write your own implementation, do not call super.onCancelled(result)." Maybe you should extend the AsyncTask to modify this behavior and have cancel() kill the thread?

Comment: Yes, I see that now. However, I thought the purpose of calling task.cancel(true) was to kill the thread, not just to bypass onPostExecute(). If automatically killing the thread isn't the purpose of calling task.cancel(true), then I can't see how I would be able to do so explicitly by extending Asynctask myself.

Comment: If there's no way to accomplish this without setting a loop and continually checking for task.isCancelled(), then I'm out of luck, essentially. I can check for it once that long-running task completes, but not kill it during, which is disappointing as I wanted to save time/CPU.

Comment: [Check out the docs for isCancelled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled()) it seems like they want you to periodically check if the task is cancelled in your doInBackground() method. Hope that helps.